# Jekyll Creating Navigation link or Tabs

Tags: navigation, jekyll

How can I fix my code in Jekyll .
I want to create navigation using */tabs/* directory I want to list all inside of the directory. I'm using gem "jekyll", "~> 4.2.0" , I Just want some clean code .

My Code Right Now ,. I want to convert my code in Jekyll

```
<a class="page-link" href="http://127.0.0.1:4000">Home</a>
<a class="page-link" href="http://127.0.0.1:4000/tabs/categories">Categories</a>
<a class="page-link" href="http://127.0.0.1:4000/tabs/tags">Tags</a>
<a class="page-link" href="http://127.0.0.1:4000/tabs/archives">Archives</a>
<a class="page-link" href="http://127.0.0.1:4000/tabs/about">About</a>
```

My Directory:

[image]

My Website Output

[image]

Sorry Newbie Question , This is my first time in here .

Comment: You'll need to explain a little better what you've got and what you're hoping to achieve. The output in the image looks like what I'd expect. Is this not what you want?

Comment: Thank you for response . I Just need to change my code to jekyll like I want loop all the file inside /tabs/ like this {% for category in sort_categories %}  <a class="page-link" href"{{ category }} {% endfor %} So I don't need to update my code every single time I add the new file for my navigation ,.  /tabs/ directory is for my navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `_data/navigation.yml` with this:

```yaml
- title: Home
  url: /
- title: Categories
  url: /tabs/categories
- title: Tags
  url: /tabs/tags
- title: Archives
  url: /tabs/archives
- title: About
  url: /tabs/about
```

Then when you want to call the navigation you can do this:

```html
{% for link in site.data.navigation %}
  <a class="page-link" href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much , Sorry to bother I just new to this Jekyll . Have a nice day